# Solving a 4th-order Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came up with a a differential equation describing the chemical kinetics of a reaction that I'm interested in:
$$
-y'(t) = k_1 y(t)^4 - k_2 (y(0) - y(t))
$$
Written as
$$
-y'(t) = k_1 y(t)^4 + k_2 y(t) - k_2 y(0)
$$
this looks like a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) of higher (4th) order?

Unfortunately, solving this equation seems to be beyond my limited math skills. I unsuccessfully tried using Mathematica, and found [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X14005083), although that didn't help me very much either.

If it helps - all constants and values are reals and positive.

Using a numerical solver, I can see that this equation nicely describes the behaviour I see - but does anyone have an idea how to solve it analytically?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(t) = -k_1 y(t)^4 - k_2 y(t) - k_3$$
This is a separable ODE:
$$dt=\frac{dy}{-k_1 y(t)^4 - k_2 y(t) - k_3}$$
$$t=-\int \frac{dy}{k_1 y(t)^4 + k_2 y(t) + k_3} +\text{constant}$$
This integral can be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. But this would be an arduous calculus.

- Solve the quartic equation $k_1r^4+k_2r+k_3=0$ for $r$. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html The roots are $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4 .$
- $$t=-\int \frac{dy}{k_1(y-r_1)(y-r_2)(y-r_3)(y-r_4)} +c$$
- Compute the coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ so that :
  $$t=\int\frac{a_1dy}{y-r_1}+\int\frac{a_2dy}{y-r_2}+\int\frac{a_3dy}{y-r_3}+\int\frac{a_4dy}{y-r_4}+c$$
- integrate in terms of logaritmic functions :
  $$t=a_1\ln|y-r_1|+a_2\ln|y-r_2|+a_3\ln|y-r_3|+a_4\ln|y-r_4|+c$$
- You have got the solution on implicit form, in fact the inverse function $t(y)$.

Probably one cannot express the inverse function $y(t)$ on explicit form with a finite number of elementary functions.